# Launch4j can't create exe - does not contain icon data

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I am using launch4j to convert my .jar file to a .exe file
Whenever I try and do this, I get an error and it only creates a .xml file

```
Compiling resources
D:\JACOB\Programming\Java\Download\Extras\Launch4j\bin\windres.exe: icon file `D:\JACOB\Programming\Java\Shutdown Program\src\shutdown.ico' does not contain icon data
Generated resource file...

net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): D:\JACOB\Programming\Java\Download\Extras\Launch4j\bin\windres.exe --preprocessor=type -J rc -O coff -F pe-i386 C:\Users\Layne\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j3403053976520062201rc C:\Users\Layne\AppData\Local\Temp\launch4j1480663534171236563o
```

This is the output I get. I have installed JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and am not sure what else to do. Here is my launch4j config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<launch4jConfig>

<dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>

<headerType>gui</headerType>

<jar>D:\JACOB\Programming\Java\Shutdown Program\out\artifacts\Shutdown_Program_jar\Shutdown Program.jar</jar>

<outfile>D:\JACOB\Programming\Java\1Output Programs\Shut down.exe</outfile>

<errTitle/>

<cmdLine/>

<chdir>.</chdir>

<priority>normal</priority>

<downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>

<supportUrl/>

<stayAlive>false</stayAlive>

<restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>

<manifest/>

<icon>D:\JACOB\Programming\Java\Shutdown Program\src\shutdown.ico</icon>


-<singleInstance>

<mutexName>SD</mutexName>

<windowTitle/>

</singleInstance>


-<jre>

<path/>

<bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>

<bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>

<minVersion>1.0.1</minVersion>

<maxVersion/>

<jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>

<runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>

</jre>

</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207228/discussion-on-question-by-jacob-why-can-i-not-convert-my-jar-file-into-a-exe-f).

Comment: i had the same problem and it was the icon file !

Answer (score 3):

> 'shutdown.ico' does not contain icon data
>
> net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: Exec failed (1): windres.exe

Your icon isn't valid and causing windres to not be able to compile the resource section for the PE.

Make sure you're creating an icon using a program that supports this or try using a png to icon conversion tool. This type of conversion tool is available on https://convertico.com/ .

Comment: So if I don't use an image it should work? or is the image compulsory and that is why it also doesn't work when there is no image

Comment: It can work without an image.

Comment: Sorry, I hate to be a pain, but when I make the .exe file without an image, and try to open it gives me this error: Error: invalid or corrupt jarfile

Comment: Ok I now have got an .exe file that I can open (I found the error as it should have been a console file not a GUI, however now when I click on it, it doesn't do what the java file did in the first place. Any suggestions??

Comment: Yes I know, I'm the same person who has been commenting on your question.  If you can't figure it out, make a new question titled "Launch4j exe invalid or corrupt jarfile" or similar.

Comment: A console file? So, should you execute it from command prompt then?